# how to setup envoy for react to call spring boot server using grpc on ec2 instance

Tags: reactjs, docker, amazon-ec2, grpc, envoyproxy

This is the github repo: https://github.com/gwengusc/react-springboot-grpc-example

Every thing works fine when I use restful api for react to call spring boot both local and ec2.

However, I want to setup grpc for the flow: react -> envoy -> springboot. It works on my local. Unfortunately, the client failed to connect to server on ec2 instance when I deployed the same things on ec2 instance. I think there must be something related to network for docker and envoy needs to be setup within ec2 instance.

To start the server, run commands `sh envoy-start.sh` ; `java -jar target/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` within the directory of server. envoy is running on docker.

To start the client, run commands `npm run start`

When it is local: the endpoint ip for react client is like:

```
const hostName:string = "http://127.0.0.1:8080"

const greetingClient = new GreetingServiceClient(hostName);
```

Every thing works fine.

The same commands for server `sh envoy-start.sh` ; `java -jar target/server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` are executed in EC2 instance.

The client endpoint ip is changed to EC2 instance public ip like:

```
const hostName:string = "http://54.218.30.252:8080"
```

The connection failed.

This is `envoy-start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

docker run -d -v "$(pwd)"/envoy.yaml:/etc/envoy/envoy.yaml:ro \
    -p 8080:8080 -p 9901:9901 envoyproxy/envoy:v1.22.0
```

this is the code for `envoy.yaml`:

```
admin:
  access_log_path: /tmp/admin_access.log
  address:
    socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 9901 }

static_resources:
  listeners:
    - name: listener_0
      address:
        socket_address: { address: 0.0.0.0, port_value: 8080 }
      filter_chains:
        - filters:
            - name: envoy.filters.network.http_connection_manager
              typed_config:
                "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.network.http_connection_manager.v3.HttpConnectionManager
                codec_type: auto
                stat_prefix: ingress_http
                route_config:
                  name: local_route
                  virtual_hosts:
                    - name: local_service
                      domains: ["*"]
                      routes:
                        - match: { prefix: "/" }
                          route:
                            cluster: greeter_service
                            timeout: 0s
                            max_stream_duration:
                              grpc_timeout_header_max: 0s
                      cors:
                        allow_origin_string_match:
                          - prefix: "*"
                        allow_methods: GET, PUT, DELETE, POST, OPTIONS
                        allow_headers: keep-alive,user-agent,cache-control,content-type,content-transfer-encoding,custom-header-1,x-accept-content-transfer-encoding,x-accept-response-streaming,x-user-agent,x-grpc-web,grpc-timeout
                        max_age: "1728000"
                        expose_headers: custom-header-1,grpc-status,grpc-message
                http_filters:
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.grpc_web
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.grpc_web.v3.GrpcWeb
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.cors
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.cors.v3.Cors
                  - name: envoy.filters.http.router
                    typed_config:
                      "@type": type.googleapis.com/envoy.extensions.filters.http.router.v3.Router
  clusters:
    - name: greeter_service
      connect_timeout: 0.25s
      type: logical_dns
      http2_protocol_options: {}
      lb_policy: round_robin
      # win/mac hosts: Use address: host.docker.internal instead of address: localhost in the line below
      load_assignment:
        cluster_name: cluster_0
        endpoints:
          - lb_endpoints:
              - endpoint:
                  address:
                    socket_address:
                      address: host.docker.internal
                      port_value: 9090
```

I expect the connection from client to EC2 instance to be successful.

Comment: Including the error that you get from gRPC would be helpful.

Also, can you confirm if you can make a TCP connection? This will rule out issues like firewall etc.